# sikulix api used in java code has error with opencv_java on linux

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, sikuli, sikuli-x

I wrote a java code to open an app and do some changes in it using sikulix api. The code works fine on windows but it gets this error on linux ubuntu:

```
[error] RunTimeAPI: loadLib: opencv_java not usable: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path
[error] RunTimeAPI:  *** terminating: problem with native library: opencv_java
```

I downloaded opencv-4.1.0 and built it then copied the generated opencv-410.jar and libopencv_java410.so files into the lib directory of the project but the error exists yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a link to libopencv_java410.so in /usr/lib/ and the problem is solved!